# 1С 8.3 (обычное). Как при сканировании со сканером обновить прорисовку табличной части документа?

Tags: 1с

Вот табличная часть (на примере 3й строки):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда вручную увеличиваем количество номенклатуры в третьей строке, то он становится жирным (скриншот прикрепил).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если увеличивать количество номенклатуры в третьей строке с помощью сканера, то здесь просто увеличивается количество на 1, то шрифт остается обычным (скриншот прикрепил).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы при сканировании штрихкода строка №3 не только увеличивался на 3, но и стал жирным (как если бы мы сделали вручную)?

Отрезок кода внешнего события:

```
Функция дкФормаВнешнееСобытие(ЭтаФорма, Источник, Событие, Данные) Экспорт

//обработка события от сканера ШК
Если Источник = "Сканер" Тогда

...

    СтрокаНоменклатура[КолСтр] = СтрокаНоменклатура[КолСтр] + 1; //Здесь количество у номенклатуры увеличивается на 1

...

КонецЕсли;

КонецФункции
```

Пробовал разные варианты обновить прорисовку (т.е. чтобы шрифт стал жирным, как если бы добавили вручную):

```
ЭтаФорма.Прочитать();
ЭтаФорма.Записать();
ЭтотОбъект.Записать();
```

и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

После присваивания нового значения, вызывайте процедуру указанную в свойствах **Колонки** *табличной части формы*, в событии *ПриИзменении* ;

Answer (score 0):

> Пробовал разные варианты обновить прорисовку (т.е. чтобы шрифт стал
> жирным, как если бы добавили вручную):

Это все не то. Тут вы полностью с объектом работаете, а вам нужно просто найти событие, в котором происходит "раскраска". Если срабатывает при изменении количества, тогда смотрите события этой колонки, либо события всей таблицы.

Comment: Я нашел событие, где срабатывает. Но как сделать так, что произошла "раскраска"?

Comment: @ВадимЧиркунов, где срабатывает, покажите код. Чтобы сделать так же, нужно переопределить (скорректировать) код, который выполняется, когда происходит сканирование сканером.